# Automatically copy/cache most used folders to ssd

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, symbolic-link, cache

i have a question about using an ssd as a hdd "cache".
I've got a spare 250gb ssd and a 3tb hdd. My HDD only contains games. Is there a good solution to copy/"cache" the games i play most to the ssd. One solution that i could imagine is to check if a directory contains an .exe that has been started more than x times in the last y days, copying the directory to the ssd if that is the case and create a symlink to the folder. Is there a solution that does this or something similar? Im open to other solutions.

PS: Im using windows 10.

Comment: Dude, 250 GB is not so much :) The one modern game can take easy up to 50 - 75 GB, so we speak abot 5-10 games here. Just copy some your favorite games and you are fine ;)

Comment: @duDE I have many games that are 10-20 GB in size. Im asking for an automatic solution because i dont want to copy my current favourite games manually every month or so.

Comment: I think nevertheless, this is rather a theoretical question. If you manage you games by a platform like Steam, you can't change the path of games in order to find and start the games.

Comment: Steam mover does that via symlinks, I'm just looking for an automatic solution.

Comment: I don't speak about a Steam mover, I mean that the solution you are looking for will not work with any platform like Steam, Epic Store, Uplay and so long!

Comment: im sorry, but i dont understand what you mean. do you mean that my proposed method to detect recently started games would not work, or that you cant move games if they are downloaded and started via steam/origin and etc. ?

Comment: You have installed the game over Steam in C:\steam\myGame. Then your tool (or whatever) has moved the game to D:\ssd_games\myGame, but Steam don't know anything about it - your link in Steam is dead.

Comment: That is what i was trying to tell you. Tools like steam mover move the folder to another location and place a symlink or something similar. For steam it looks like nothing has changed.